# How can I extract the whole HTML of a page - before and after the DOM?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to find a way to extract the HTML code of a web page using JavaScript in two editions:

Before the DOM / Before JS is applied
After the DOM / After JS is applied

All the JavaScript methods that I know just take it from the DOM element, like document.body or document.all... but non of them work specifically for before or after the DOM.

Added:
Just to focus the question further, this is not my page so I can't install any  on the page, this is for any random web page.

Can you point me in the right direction? is there a specific method/command/process that is used in JavaScript and can do that? maybe I should stop the page load at specific point and take the code and then let it continue loading and take the code with the JS included?

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you put a `<script />` tag in the middle of your `HTML` your code will get executed before the continuation of the rest of your HTML.

also you can use

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
```

to call your function when the `DOM` is ready (it comes in the name of the event listener so sorry for over-explaination!)

Getting all the stuff is easy via the `window` object, can not imagine anything else you might need.

So if you want to do something before the `DOM` loads just put a `<script />` tag at the top. if you want the dom to be ready use the `DOMContentLoaded`.

You can find great and complete documentation on this subject of [script, async, defer](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer) on **javascript.info**. if there is anything that my explanation did not cover for you.

Comment: It's not my page, any webpage.

Comment: You can probably stop the page load in the dev tools and add the event listener.

Comment: How do I stop the page load?

Comment: I was wrong I do not know a way to stop the loading of the page from dev tools, sorry.